# Gradle JUnit forks

Tags: gradle, junit, fork

I have a project where I am running the tests using Gradle, and I am setting the property `maxParallelForks` to n (some number greater than 1) based on the number of processors on my build machine. In my case every test **run** needs a unique id that is generated once and passed on to all the tests. This id is generated programmatically in the base class of the test, and stored in a static variable. The tests check if it is null in which case a new id is generated (happens at the start of the run), if not they use the existing id. Thus the same id is used by all the tests in that particular run.

When I run the Gradle tests without `maxParallelFors`, then it works fine. However, with forking, I see that every test finds the value null initially which prompts it to generate its own id. Is Gradle creating a separate "JVM" process for each individual test? Seems like static variables are not shared when I enable forking in Gradle. I cannot set this as an environment variable, since it needs to be programmatically generated. How can I address this issue?

Comment: You could invoke the programmatic code from the Gradle build to set the environment variable before the tests start.  You could alter the tests to only generate the unique id if the environment variable does not exist, thus allowing your tests to run outside of Gradle too.